# Is it possible to listen only debugger directed to a certain debugport?

Tags: debugging, serial-port, protocols, vmware, remote-debugging

I'm [trying to connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454829/how-do-i-connect-to-the-vmwares-pipe-and-receive-debug-information-from-the-runn) to the VMWare's pipe; what is in fact simulated serial port where I've redirected debug output from the virtual OS. I used [this article](http://silverstr.ufies.org/lotr0/windbg-vmware.html) to redirect debug output from the virtual OS to the named pipe on my client OS through the VMWare. It works perfectly when I use the WinDbg as decribed in [that article](http://silverstr.ufies.org/lotr0/windbg-vmware.html) but I want to create my own application to catch this debug output - only to catch, nothing else. When I'm only listening from the pipe (that simulated serial port) I'm getting meaningless data.

Is it enough to only read from the remote debugger (redirected to a certain debugport) or should I use some protocol for it (to acknowledge reading or something) ? In other words; may I only listen to the pipe (serial port) without any response to it ?

Thanks for any suggestions
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data coming out is not meaningless but it has to be parsed based on the particular protocol used. If you are not sending commands but just reading output information it should be enough to just listen (though I do not know off hand if the protocol requires acknowledgement of messages).

However, what you receive will have to be parsed based on the messages you are getting. I've never tried to parse the debug information on my own but [this page](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84367/kernel-and-remote-debuggers/) should give you some information on the protocol.

Comment: +1 and accept; thanks for the initial reading. This would be [hardcore](http://www.qqread.com/soft-engineering/e300828.html) :)